# How to get URL Params with Node JS Http/Https module

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, parameters, url-routing

I am programming the backend of my web application. And I'm doing the api and I need to be able to send data in the URLs. For example:

```
www.example.com/posts/123456789
```

Right now all I have is:

```
www.example.com/posts/?q=123456789
```

I would like to know if I could do something similar to what the express module does with the colon to declare params. But I want to do it with the node http module as I have already written all the routing with it and it would be a huge pain to move to express and have to memorize the functions for it.

if this isn't possible please let me know and I will have to stick to the query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like [HTTP module docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) do not specify a way to do this, other than by using [search params](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#class-urlsearchparams).

In your case however, I think that the best course of action (if migrating to a framework like express is not an option) would be to manually deconstruct the URL with using something like:
`const urlSegments = request.url.split('/')`
and taking n-th segment (matching the route you specified).

This is a bad solution in the long term, as it would be quite difficult to maintain, but it can get the job done if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for this solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you would do something like this.

I will give you whole server code, just pass it and run it.To see it for yourself

What this code does is for example -> localhost:8080/month?9 when you pass this into the browser the console will print out the 9

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  const queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query; <---- Here is where you "catch" the URI parameters
  console.log(queryObject); <-- here you display them

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end('Feel free to add query parameters to the end of the url');
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: what I am looking for is for example instead of ```localhost:8080/month?9``` it's ```localhost:8080/month/9```. 
Like in express how you would do: 
```app.get('/test/:id', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.id)
  //then all the res.write and stuff
})```
then I would go to ```localhost:8000/test/apple``` and it would console log "apple".

Comment: Well there are multiple ways you could do that, basically the way I would do it is replace queryobject with this   const queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).pathname;
and slice the resulti string into smaller segments and use that.Sadly I do not know how to do this properly and I do not know if this the proper way of handling such requests. I would use the aproach I did above or completely switch to express